# drag and drop not working on iPAD

Tags: ipad, bbc-glow

I would like to use sortable HTML tables driven by a Javascript API (e.g., BBC Glow) with the iPAD - however, I cannot drag an otherwise draggable item using the iPAD as the entire page scrolls instead of the element I would like to drag.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

was just about to ask this same question... but in a different way.  no, iPad does not support the idea of "double clicking" or "drag/drop"... so my question was going to be "what are best-practices for modifying an existing UI so that it works for iPad/iPhone?"

ran across this project while researching:
  http://www.gotproject.com/blog/post2.html

I would start by looking over how this guy's code works, and try something like that...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, use jquery UI http://jqueryui.com/demos/ for drag and drop functionality

and then add this script https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch for playing it in Ipad or Iphone.

Hope it helps.